# PHP MySQL - Images uploaded to mysql doesnt show up on php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im trying to create a way to upload images to a page but when i load the page i get the following result: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAJ92.png)

Why arent the images showing up? im cofused.

I have been hours trying to find the solution but i end up in the same place.

Code:

```html
<?php
  // Create database connection
    include ('config.php');
  // Initialize message variable
  $msg = "";

  // If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get image name
    $image = $_FILES['IMG_Link']['IMG_Name'];
    // Get text
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['IMG_Name']);

    // image file directory
    $target = "GenFeed/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO GenFeed (IMG_Link, IMG_Name) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['IMG_Link']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM GenFeed");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Upload</title>
<style type="text/css">
   #content{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   form{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 20px auto;
   }
   form div{
    margin-top: 5px;
   }
   #img_div{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
   }
   #img_div:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
   }
   img{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 140px;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<div id='img_div'>";
        echo "<img src='GenFeed/".$row['IMG_Link']."' >";
        echo "<p>".$row['IMG_Name']."</p>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  ?>
    <form method="POST" action="ImageUpload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="IMG_Link">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea 
        id="text" 
        cols="40" 
        rows="4" 
        name="IMG_Name" 
        placeholder="Say something about this image..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope you guys can help me out on this one

PD: im aware the im using superglobal variables

Comment: Is there a difference here between the absolute and relative paths? Your `move_uploaded_file` will need to use the absolute path for the filesystem, whereas your `<img src` will use one relative to the root of the web site. Where is "GenFeed/" in comparison to the web root and your PHP directory?

Comment: im sorry but im kinda newbie on all of this, "GenFeed" is located on a database ("create") how do i see it absolute path? its supposed to be on "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data" but such directory doesnt exists (apparently), the Web is located on xampp htdocs folder

Comment: No, I don't mean the path of the database, I mean the path of the images, since that's the problem you are having. The `img src` path will need to be a virtual path, relative to your web root, whereas the path used as the destination in `move_uploaded_file` is a filesystem path, relative to the root. For example if your web root is in c:\wampp\www\sitename and you have a folder called "images", you'd only use "images" in the img tag, but probably have to use more when you move the file.